# Consider flag weight as well as reputation for earning moderation tools

Tags: feature-request, reputation, 10k-tools, flag-weight

Users who have shown they are responsible wielders of moderator flags should be able to access [moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) at lower reputation levels.

Comment: It seems that we need both a proposed floor and a proposed formula. I like 5k for the floor so the user gets some time to use the close power before getting access to the lists.

Comment: @dmckee: I spent a minute thinking about the formula.  But, without knowing how flag weights are calculated it isn't worth spending more time on it.

Comment: FYI: This question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92319/flagging-too-little-too-late also relate the same issue. Take a look (don't know if it is duplicate or would need a merge here?)

Comment: @Marc: am curious, did anything come of the discussion?

Comment: @raz it's a pretty radical subversion of the 10k privilege, and there's the issue of how to notify the users they have it, etc.

Comment: @jeff - thanks. The notification issue aside, is it infeasible to e.g. allow high flag weight users access to the flag handling tools alone? I can well understand that it might be a considerable amount of work.

Answer (score 13):

Considering the "Deputy × 243" statistic, I agree with this. How many 10K user are in stackoverflow? if you know?

#### Edit: statistics for the records (20th of May 2011)

Ran from https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1249/count-the-number-of-deputy-with-less-than-10k-reputation

```
Deputy                                : 319
Deputy with less than 10K             : 172 (54%)
Deputy with less than 10K and >= 1K   : 142 (44%)
Deputy with less than 10K and >= 1,5K : 121 (38%)
Deputy with less than 10K and >= 2K   : 104 (32%)
Deputy with less than 10K and >= 3K   : 78  (24%)
Deputy with less than 10K and >= 5K   : 41  (12%)
Deputy with less than 10K and >= 7K   : 23  ( 7%)
```

Comment: 1113 according to the last datadump.

Comment: I like your link @Bobby. You can now consider : http://data.stackexchange.com/cookingmeta/s/1249/count-the-number-of-deputy-with-less-than-10k-reputation show that 73 users are in this case.

Comment: Apologise, it was @Will linking, but I bet the same result come from the same site :P. BTW there is also the average reputation in the query.