# Flagging: too little, too late?

Tags: discussion, flags

Every time I flag a question for migration I see a good number of related questions that could be flagged for migration as well.

It's also to easy to find tags where most posts tagged so belong to, say, serverfault -- try the 5K+ questions tagged IIS.

Either give us (you have 331 Deputies and it's growing fast when I got mine a few days ago there were only 328) a lot of flags for cleanups or ... abandon trying...?

Comment: I don't think that every question tagged `IIS` should be moved to SF. There are grey zones.

Comment: Of course, I didnt mean that every of them -- I meant *most*. I wonder why I got voted down :(

Comment: On meta, voting down indicates disagreement. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/why-are-people-downvoting-my-question-on-meta

Comment: Many questions about IIS are by **programmers** configuring IIS via the various API's or about how IIS interacts with site code (eg, IIS7 influences the behaviour of ASP and ASP.NET depending app pool config). All of the IIS tags are favourited by me (one of my pet subjects) and I certainly have no hesitation about asking for pure administration questions to be migrated to SF. Other typical IIS questions are about writing modules, handlers and filters. Also there are some grey areas - scripting config via PowerShell (which I happen to think is programming related). Just my 2c there :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Matt indicated, it is OK for there to be overlap in topics. Not every grandfathered in question *has* to be moved to a new site.

However, I do support moving the "best of" questions to new sites that didn't exist at the time the original questions were asked.

So, when you flag for migration, try to flag the really great questions to seed the newer sites and help them grow. The giant mass of good to average questions don't necessarily need to be migrated, but I like to see the "greatest hits" get migrated to their new homes.

Comment: why not have a _copy_ of the "best of" questions there instead of moving it completely. That way SO newbies (who don't know of the other sites) can also benefit from it.

Comment: @yoda Google has special penalties for duplicate content. We get 90% of our traffic from Google. Very, very bad idea.

Comment: @Jeff: Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @yoda: In addition it's worth noting that users are automatically redirected to the target site when navigating to migrated questions - this means links aren't *broken* by the migration, and also that users who find the originals interesting are introduced to the new site - something that wouldn't happen if the question was left open at it's original location.

Comment: @Shog9: That is a good point. I'm however not sure if the best of post, once migrated, will continue to enjoy the same number of votes it had or if it will be reset (in which case it will no longer be accessible from the "votes" tab)... In any case, do you think a cross-site "best-of" page (accessible from any SE site with that same tag) would be a good idea? That way a user can, from within SO, see a top rated post on SU/SF etc and follow it if they so wish.

Comment: @yoda: You can visit http://stackexchange.com/ to view the current "hot" questions across all sites... "Best of" is tricky though, since different sites have *vastly* different traffic levels (...and audiences). That said, a migrated post *will* retain votes - although they don't (normally) contribute to the reputation of the user on the target site.

Comment: @Shog9: Yeah, I know about the hot questions... but I agree with you that "best of" might be harder to implement. Thanks for the rest of the info.

Comment: @Shog9: To your first comment one should add that after some time the migrated question will be _deleted_ on the orginal site. (Seems to be after at most a month.)

Comment: @Shog9: You're mistaken if you say "they don't (normally) contribute to the reputation of the user on the target site" (although this _used_ to be the case). See this answer of Nick Craver: [Migrated posts lose their pre-migration reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78452/migrated-posts-lose-their-pre-migration-reputation/88066#88066).

Comment: @Hendrik: w00t! Didn't realize that'd been... changed/fixed! But note that the redirect works even after the original question has been deleted.

Comment: @Shog9: Erm, do you mean the redirect still works for 10K users?

Comment: @Hendrik: the redirect should still work for low-rep users regardless of whether or not they can actually *see* the original question. 10K users (on the origin site) *can* still view it once deleted.

Comment: @Shog9: Ah, I think I start understanding what you mean. If someone _links_ to a question that gets migrated later on, that link will still work and redirect you to the destination site. Ah yes, you even wrote that above. I guess I read it, but I fail to remember `:-)`